# Nvidia Flex soft body constraint type

Tags: particles, nvidia-flex

When creating a soft body in Nvidia Flex using `NvFlexExtCreateSoftFromMesh()` which results in particles grouped together in clusters, which constraint type of Position-Based Dynamics will be used? Is it shape matching or general distance constraints or something else?

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this manual: https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/gameworkslibrary/physx/flex/manual.html, each cluster is held together with shape matching constraints. The soft body as a whole is held together by the fact that each particle can be a member of multiple clusters.

`NvFlexExtCreateSoftFromMesh()` also receives a float parameter called `linkRadius`. If you provide a linkRadius larger than `particleSpacing`, the function will additionally create springs (regular distance constraints) between the particles in the soft body.